# What is the "updater" in Plesk control panel actually updating?

Tags: package-management, update

Is it performing operating system package updates (with yum or what-have-you)?

Or is it just updating Plesk itself?

As a bonus question, if it *isn't* performing operating system package updates, then how does one do that with a Plesk server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a lot of cases, specifically on Ubuntu or Debian servers, the Plesk Updater does the task of running apt-get upgrade. Since the Plesk repositories are in /etc/apt/sources, the Updater runs apt-get upgrade to get the latest Plesk files and in the case of my Ubuntu server, do other system package updates IF those are a dependency to the plesk packages being updated.

If you don't want to rely on Plesk Updater for operation system-level security and software updates, then for Ubuntu/Debian based servers, you can use apt-get or for Red Hat servers, use yum.

Comment: I had the same question. Do you know if this is mentioned in the official PLESK/Virtuozzo docs somewhere ?